# Can't find image, but src is correct

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a div at the bottom of the page that contains an image that changes based on a page variable. Here is my code to set the image:

```
<div>
    <p>Data from @ViewBag.site.</p>
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>

<script>
        var site = '@(ViewBag.site)';
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        switch(site){
            case "WeatherUnderground":
                elem.src = '~/Images/wunderground.jpg';
                break;
            case "Forecast.io":
                elem.src = '~/Images/fio.jpg';
                break;
            case "NOAA":
                elem.src = '~/Images/noaa.png';
                break;
            case "WeatherUnlocked":
                elem.src = '~/Images/wunlocked.jpg';
                break;
            case "APIXU":
                elem.src = '~/Images/apixu.jpg';
                break;
            case "OpenWeatherMap":
                elem.src = '~/Images/owm.jpg';
                break;
        }
        elem.setAttribute("height", 100);
        elem.setAttribute("width", 133);
        elem.setAttribute("alt", site);
        document.getElementById("logo").appendChild(elem);
</script>
```

When I visit this page, the image doesn't show up (instead, the alternate text plus black square/X combination shows up). When I inspect the alternate image, I see that it has the correct source. If I copy the source path into the browser, it does take me to the image, so I know the source is correct. However, the picture isn't showing up, so obviously something is wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Network tab of the console when it tries loading the images?

Comment: Can you open Console on Developer tools and write what message you see there? Chrome: PC: Ctrl + Shift + J Mac: Cmd + Opt +

Comment: Sometimes, capitalisation causes assets for a 404. I see, you have capital 'I' in images. You can check if indeed that is correct.

Comment: Your switch is testing a constant string `var site = '@(ViewBag.site)';` and I don't see it in any of your case statements, so the `elem.src` is probably never set. You may want to check that. And if you're going to be coding for the web, you should learn how to debug with Chrome dev tools https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: @ankitjain11 thanks for the idea, but the folder is also capitalized, so it's correct.

Comment: @kennasoft see the comments on the answer below

Comment: This is strange. Is it possible to isolate this problem and put it online where others can actually take a look? Because it sounds absurd that an image with the correct src is having the problems you are describing.

Comment: Some sites refuse to serve images to an external domain. They do that by checking the referrer but usually do not block the content when there's no referrer at all (which would explain why it works when you copy/paste the URL). That said, I see you are using relative paths. So I suppose these images are supposed to be served from the server that's hosting the page?

Comment: @kennasoft Unfortunately I can't put it online yet.

Comment: @Arnauld Elsewhere on the site I include one of the same images, but the src is set inline in the html, because it's always the same image. This one is showing up fine, so that leads me to believe that there is some problem with the code I have above, but then, it does seem absurd since it has the correct src.

Comment: @issharp - Unless it's confidential, could you share a full URL of one of the images?

Comment: @Arnauld the images are actually from photos on my computer--they're stored in a folder in the project called Images (so I'm happy to post one but I don't know that it'd be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a switch statement against a string that never changes.

```
 var site = '@(ViewBag.site)';
```

But there is no case in your switch statement for this string so elem.src is never set.

Comment: `@(ViewBag.site)` is most probably a placeholder that's replaced once the template has been pre-processed (that's the Razor syntax, I think).

Comment: I had never heard of Razor until this moment so was thinking in terms of pure JavaScript. Does this mean we need to request more info?

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is elsewhere since the OP said he inspected the image and saw the correct modified source. We definitely need more info anyway.

Comment: @Arnauld that's correct--I'm using MVC, if that helps. And elem.src is set--when I inspect the element, the image has the correct src set (the tag looks like this: <img width="133" height="100" src="~/Images/wunderground.jpg" /> which is the correct src)